# Listing files from folder to table view

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added a folder called "Audio" to my xcode project using 'recursively create groups for any added folders'.

The folder contains some audio songs. I want to generate a song list taking the songs from the added folder dynamically. Please help me how to do that.

I can create song list if the folder is added using folder reference. But I do not want that.

Comment: I can create song list if the folder is added using folder reference. But I do not want that.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 NSArray * thelist
   =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
```

Straight from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
 NSString * audioPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Audio"];
 
NSArray *audioContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:audioPath error:nil];

Comment: I have used the code above but its not working.The folder is added as "Recursively create groups for any added folder" into the project. But unable to list the songs in a table view.....